# Can I just replace the heating coil in my dryer, or do I have to do the whole element?

Tags: electrical, repair, heating, dryer, appliances

My dryer heating coil in my heating element broke in two. It seems like it'll be simple enough to just put a new coil in and be on my way. The part is available and this move would save me about $40. Which is good; I'm not exactly rolling in it right now. The thermal fuse is still good and everything else in the dryer has worked fine; are there any reasons I should spend the extra money and replace the whole thing, or is just swaping to a new coil sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The coil[s] can be replaced. I've done mine twice. Coil failure indicates inefficient venting, so it's worth looking at the the vents while doing the job.